# How to set default value to set Map and/or then value++ for each in JS

Tags: javascript, foreach, count

```
const salaries = {
  Progger: {salary: 1000, tax: '15%'},
  Tester: {salary: 800, tax: '10%'},
  Manager: { salary: 1000, tax: '10%' },
  Designer: { salary: 600, tax: '30%' },
  Artist: { salary: 1500, tax: '15%' }
};

const team = [
  { name: 'Vasya', specialization: 'Tester' },
  { name: 'Taras', specialization: 'Tester' },
  { name: 'Taras I', specialization: 'Tester' },
  { name: 'Tapas', specialization: 'Humor' },
  { name: 'Misha', specialization: 'Manager' },
  { name: 'Max', specialization: 'Designer' },
  { name: 'Vova', specialization: 'Designer' },
  { name: 'Leo', specialization: 'Artist' }
];

function calculateTeamFinanceReport(salaries, team) {
  const proffNames = Object.keys(salaries);
  let proffesions = new Map();
  let result = {};
  let value;

  // for (let every of proffNames) {
  //   proffesions.set(every, 0)
  // }

  for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
    let specialization = team[i].specialization;
    if (proffNames.some(proffesion => {   //specialisation has to be salaries `team.specialization == salaries[any]`
      if (specialization === proffesion) {
        value = value || 0;
        proffesions.set(proffesion, value++); // Right count here needed
      }
    }))
      i++;
  }
  return proffesions
}
```

Result = 'Progger' => 1, 'Tester' => 4, 'Manager' => 5, 'Designer' => 7, 'Artist' => 8

I need to count here how much people have exact profession. Instead I get total count.
Also `specialisation` from `team` has to be in `salaries`, else = ignore and continue.

```
team.specialization == salaries[any]
```

How to get right count for each profession?
Or how to set default value `1` for `proffesions` map object an then ++ it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `value` is `salaries[proffesion]['salary']`
- If there isn't a `proffesion` in the `dept` object (`result = {}` originally), then add it to `dept` object and `.set()` it in `proffesions` Map.
- Then `.get()` the `proffesion` from `proffesions` Map and add the `value` to the `salary` in `dept[proffesion]`
- Finally `.set()` the new `value` to `proffesions` Map.

```js
const salaries={Programmer:{salary:1e3,tax:"15%"},Tester:{salary:800,tax:"10%"},Manager:{salary:1e3,tax:"10%"},Designer:{salary:600,tax:"30%"},Executive:{salary:1500,tax:"15%"}},team=[{name:"Vasya",specialization:"Tester"},{name:"Taras",specialization:"Tester"},{name:"Taras I",specialization:"Tester"},{name:"Tapas",specialization:"Programmer"},{name:"Misha",specialization:"Manager"},{name:"Max",specialization:"Designer"},{name:"Vova",specialization:"Designer"},{name:"Leo",specialization:"Executive"},
{name:"Ivan",specialization:"Unemployed"}];

function calculateTeamFinanceReport(salaries, team) {
  const proffNames = Object.keys(salaries);
  let proffesions = new Map();
  let dept = {};
  let value = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
    let specialization = team[i].specialization;
    proffNames.forEach(proffesion => {
      if (specialization === proffesion) {
        value = salaries[proffesion]['salary'] || 0;
        if (!dept[proffesion]) {
          proffesions.set(proffesion, 0);
          dept[proffesion] = 0;
        }
        dept[proffesion] = value;
        let v = proffesions.get(proffesion);
        value = v + value;
        proffesions.set(proffesion, value);
      }
    });
  }
  return proffesions
}

console.log(Array.from(calculateTeamFinanceReport(salaries, team).entries()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function totalMembers(teams, selectedTeam) {
     return teams.filter(team => team === selectedTeam)?.length;
 }
```

this function will return the total members for the provided team in teams array.

```
function calculateTeamFinanceReport(salaries, team) {
    const teamHashTable = {};
    let totalMember = 1;
    for (const specialization in salaries) {
        const teamSpecializations = team.map(t => t.specialization);
        totalMember += totalMembers(teamSpecializations, specialization);
        teamHashTable[specialization] = totalMember;
    }
    return teamHashTable;
}
```

Taking the `totalMember` for the specialization then saving that for the specialization and then starts from there for next turn and so on.

Output: [image]

Hope this answer would help!